# Shared variable in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm working on a iOS app. I want to store the username and the id of the connected user to use them in other functions but I don't know how. 
I tried to make a static variables and use them.

This is my code:

My API call:

```
class func getID()-> String {
    return LoginViewController.id
}

class func getusername()-> String {
    return LoginViewController.username
}
```

LoginViewController:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textUsername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textPassword: UITextField!
    static var username = ""
    static var id = ""
    var myUser = [User]()

    //TODO Connect with facebook

    @IBAction func LoginBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        //TODO
        //Controle de Saisie
        API.login(username: textUsername.text!, password: textPassword.text!) { success in
            if success{
                let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
                let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainPage") as! MainPageViewController
                nextViewController.currentUser = self.textUsername.text!
                self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
                API.getUser(username: self.textUsername.text!) { (error :Error?, myUser :[User]?) in
                    if let myUser = myUser {
                        self.myUser = myUser
                        self.reloadInputViews()

                        print("hey")
                        print(myUser[0].username)
                        LoginViewController.username = myUser[0].username
                        LoginViewController.id = String(myUser[0].id)
                    //  API.create(id: String(myUser[0].id), money: String(myUser[0].money), username: String(myUser[0].username))

                      //  print(String(myUser[0].id))
                         // API.create()

                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("no")
            }
        }
```

And when I'm trying to use them like this , I get no result :

```
API.getTransaction(username: API.getID(),type : "target") { (error :Error?, transactions : [Transaction]?) in
    if let transactions = transactions {
        self.transactions = transactions
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to check if your api call is receiving the ID .  Also, it is better to use simple UserDefaults to store and retrieve User Information.

Comment: you can use _keychain_ to store sensitive user information.

Answer (score 0):

Present the next view controller after "Get User" . As you are assigning data in Get User.

- Try using User Defaults for saving User Information.

  - For Saving

`let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set("My.User", forKey: "User_ID")
defaults.set("My.Name", forKey: "User_Name")`

- For Retreiving

`let user_id = defaults.string(forKey: "User_ID") ?? ""`